# ¿Cómo calcular matriz de demandas medias semanales por cliente?

Tags: r

os muestro los primeros datos de mi fichero:

```
 Solicitante latitude longitude Entrega `Cantidad entrega` `Peso total` Volumen_x   Fecha
        <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>    2020-08-03
1     1000457     40.3     -3.76  8.59e9                3        26.4       36.8    2020-08-03
2     1000457     40.3     -3.76  8.59e9                1         8.52      12.2    2020-08-03
3     1000457     40.3     -3.76  8.59e9                3        26.0       36.8    2020-08-03
4     1000457     40.3     -3.76  8.59e9                1         8.6       12.3    2020-08-03
5     1000457     40.3     -3.76  8.59e9                1         8.8       12.3    2020-08-03
6     1000457     40.3     -3.76  8.59e9                1         8.52      12.2    2020-08-03
```

Tengo los datos de todos los días del mes de agosto.
Necesito calcular para cada id de Solicitante la demanda media de:
Peso total y Cantidad entrega .

¿Cómo debo hacerlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por el ejemplo que muestras pareciera que estás usando `dplyr`. La forma de resolverlo es mediante una agrupamiento y sumarización:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Solicitante,
           nSemana=strftime(Fecha, format = "%V")) %>% 
  summarise(`Peso total (media)` = mean(`Peso total`),
            `Cantidad entrega (media)` = mean(`Cantidad entrega`))
```

En caso de tener valores faltantes, a la hora de calcular la media, puedes agregar el parámetro `na.rm=TRUE` a la función `mean()`.